# What is the best way to implement a theme / template in meteor or angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I've been having trouble implementing templates bought in themeforest in a meteor app.

I'm wondering, what would the best way to implement a template into a meteor app.

Two ways that I think of right now are:

(Tedious way)
Place javascript in Compatibility folder and try to name them in specific alphabetic order in order to get them to work properly.

Place css in client/lib folder and try to name them in specific alphabetic order in order to get them to work properly.

Place fonts and images in the public folder.

The second way (I haven't tested it yet) is to place the template files in the public folder and just link them manually (the old/non-meteor way) in the index.html file.

Now I'm not sure if these are the correct ways to do this and I would like some information regarding this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this myself with a themeforest theme.

1. Put the theme's css file under /client - it doesn't need to be in /public
2. Use the class names your theme uses in your templates. Typically a theme will have 3x what you really need so this ends up being much less work than it might seem. If your theme is built on bootstrap then it's even easier.
3. My theme used fontello a lot for icons, I had to recreate the folder hierarchy under client/fonts and then make sure the cross-references were correct.

Typically themeforest themes don't use js that much, I completely ignored all the js that came with my theme and created what I really needed in Meteor.

Comment: I see. Most of the themes that I'm interested have some sort of slideshow which has javascript libraries, how would be the best way to implement these?

Comment: These are typically called _carousels_. There are many carousel packages for Meteor, for example [richsilv:owl-carousel](https://atmospherejs.com/richsilv/owl-carousel) or [udondan:slick](https://atmospherejs.com/udondan/slick)

Comment: I usually use http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848 which has a lot of javascript content and I have been struggling to implement it in a meteor project.